# Load next page and wait for click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

I'm just building a small game, so i loading the first page (Intro) and then, i need immediately start loading the Second page (The 1st level of the Game, **but just load**, without show it), and **then wait for the user click** to Show it..

**Here is my code for now:**

in my html page:

```
<body id="loadlevel">
```

in my JS page:

```
var level1 = "level1.html";
$("#loadlevel").load(level1).fadeIn("slow");
```

But it show the loaded page immediately!..

**How can i load the next page and then wait for the user input to show the loaded page?..**

I though to use the JQuery hide() and show(), but hide() will hide the entire page (Also the current page) ;)

Comment: you can load it to the hidden field, and then show it

Comment: Do you need the url in you browser to be changed? If no you can try the trick with 2 iframes: one with current level is visible, the other one is hidden and preloading. On click just show the next, hide current and start to preload next level.

Comment: Why do we need iframes, when we can just use divs?

Comment: @pxx - I wouldn't recommend using iframes.

Comment: @LazKarimov, preloaded page could contain not only HTML but CSS and JS as well. It could affect the present one.

Comment: If the content of the next page does not refer to other web sites, then all the css and js are already included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create some invisible field and load data.

```
<div id="temp" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Then in JS

```
var level1 = "level1.html";
$("#temp").load(level1);
```

and

```
$('#start').click(function(){
   $('#main').html($('#temp').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to have a main div that's initially hidden with css or jquery, then load the content into there and fadein.

Answer (score 0):

`.load()`-loads data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none are in progress, jQuery triggers the ajaxStart event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxStart() method are executed at this time.

css:

```
.get-in{
   background:white;
   position:absolute; // or fixed
   left:0;
   top:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#loadlevel').ajaxStart(function() {
  $('<div/>').appendTo('body').addClass('get-in');
});

$('.get-in').on('click', function(){
   $(this).fadeOut("slow");
});
```